# Having trouble updating to use if Locust v1.5.3

Tags: locust

I was using an older version of Locust (V1.4.3) and I want to move to the latest V1.5.3.

My testing environment is a little wonky so I have to directly indicate success or failure.  Here is the code I was using with the older version

```
  def RunTask(self, kind, name, task):
    # Run indicated smoke test container command
    start = time()
    code, logs = RunTestTask(self.environment, kind, name, task)
    total = time() - start
    # Tell locust the resuslts
    test = "{0}-{1}:{2}".format(kind, splitext(name)[0], task)
    if code:
      self.client.request_failure.fire(request_type    = "runtask",
                                       name            = test,
                                       response_time   = total,
                                       response_length = 0,
                                       exception       = None)
    else:
      self.client.request_success.fire(request_type    = "runtask",
                                       name            = test,
                                       response_time   = total,
                                       response_length = 0)
```

The latest version has deprecated the request_failure and request_success have been deprecated.  The new version has a unified request method for both but I have not been able to figure out how to properly indicate success or failure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any truthy value for the exception parameter to request.fire to indicate a failure. You could basically replace the whole if-block with

```
self.environment.events.request.fire(
     request_type="runtask",
     name=test,
     response_time=total,
     response_length=0,
     exception=code,
     context={},
)
```

The long story: The new way uses only the exception field to differentiate between success and failure. This is a bit weird, but happened anyway in the built in Users (it was impossible to report a failure in HttpUser without an exception). So I thought it unnecessary to add an extra parameter indicating success or fail.

Comment: Thanks!  I will try that out.

Comment: Ok, I tried the code above and it failed with a message indicating that request has no method named fire.  I took off the fire and it fails with a message indicating that two other parameters are required: method, url.  I think that I need to reference a different request item but I am not sure how.

Comment: Yea, sorry I had just copy pasted your code. I will correct my answer...